# A locally compact, connected metric space is $\sigma$-compact

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading the first book in Spivak's series on differential geometry and have been kind of stumped by one of his early arguments on page 5.

First he notes that if $X$ is locally compact then there is an $r > 0$ so that the set

$$ \{y: d(x, y) \leq r\}$$

is compact. He the defines $r(x)$ to be one-half of the supremum over all such $r$. He then seeks to argue that $r(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ by noting that

$$
\{y: d(x_{1},y) \leq r \} \subset \{y: d(x_{2}, y) \leq r + d(x_{1}, x_{2})\}, 
$$

by the triangle inequality, and therefore also:

$$
\{y: d(x_{1},y) \leq r - d(x_{1}, x_{2}) \} \subset \{y: d(x_{2}, y) \leq r\}.
$$

He then concludes that this implies that

$$r(x_{1}) \geq r(x_{2}) - \frac{1}{2}d(x_{1},x_{2}).$$

The second half of his argument makes sense after this point but I don't see how he arrived at this inequality.

Comment: It looks like he's taking some sort of supremum over the two sets, then dividing by $2$. I don't really understand though either... hopefully somebody else will

Comment: Did he mention  the case where $r(x)=\infty$ for some $x$?  Of course it's trivial as then the closure of every open ball is compact  and $r(x)=\infty$ for all $x.$(E,g, if $X=\mathbb R$ with the usual metric.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a>0$ be such that $\bar B_a(x_2)$ is compact. By the last inequality, $\bar B_{a-d(x_1,x_2)}(x_1)$ is within this ball, and hence is also compact. Since the function $r(x_1)$ is half the sup of such radii (of balls centered at $x_1$), $2r(x_1)\ge a-d(x_1,x_2)$. Taking the $\sup$ of this over such $a$ gives $2r(x_1)\ge 2r(x_2)-d(x_1,x_2)$.